# Undo Show Desktop on Mac Pro OS 10.10

Tags: desktop-customization

I did the thumb/three finger swipe to move all the open windows to the borders.  However, I cannot undo this action!  All my windows are on the borders, some of which I cannot even grab.  F11 does NOT work.  Command D does NOT work.  What DOES work??   Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally do the opposite of the gesture (although for "binary" do/undo swipes, repeating the gesture also works), so in your case, do a thumb and three finger pinch.

System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures is where that and other gestures are configured, and if you hover over (or click) the gesture on the left, the little clip on the right demonstrates the gesture and undoing it.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my earlier post that this did not work either.  The three finger pinch brought up the Launch Application.  However, good news is that by turning the pad feature off, and then turning it back on and doing the open/close motion with the thumb and three fingers did work.  It's almost like it needed a reset.  Thanks for helping and making me try again!

Comment: @Doug Cool, glad you got it working. Maybe the preferences got corrupted somehow and turning it off then back on caused them to be rewritten, correctly this time. Silly computers...